# Dereferencing pointers to members of union

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code prints '2' four times. Why does it never print '1'? Can someone explain me exactly what is happening here?

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    union IntegersUnion {

        int a;
        int b;
    };

    IntegersUnion q;

    q.a = 1;
    q.b = 2;

    std::cout << "(*(&q.a)) = " << (*(&q.a)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(*(&q.b)) = " << (*(&q.b)) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "(*(&(q.a))) = " << (*(&(q.a))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(*(&(q.b))) = " << (*(&(q.b))) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you *understand* what a `union` is?

Comment: Apparently I don't. I just read some documentation but it seems I missed the point.

Comment: The pertinent question is what @curvature thought it did. That's what I'm dying to know.

Comment: I thought it was a simpler version of a struct. From the answers here I finally understood what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `union` shares the memory between its members. By doing:

```
q.a = 1;
q.b = 2;
```

the second assignment overwrites the `a`.

Comment: So what happens then if I had a union of an `int` and some other different object?

Comment: the union would be the size of the largest entry in its list. And yes, you can totally fry your program or memory by putting one thing in, and taking it out as the other.

Comment: Best use for a union is mutually exclusive data when available memory is small, or transferring data across a pipe. Even then, you should have some way of identifying which variable was assigned. That could be a flag, or it could be the meaning of the data as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

`union` uses the same memory for all of its members.

So, when you assign `q.b = 2;`, `q.a` will be `2`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Every item in the `union` refers to the same location.

The most common use of `union` is something like this:

```
struct {
    int dataTypeID;
    union {
        char char_here;
        int number_here;            
    }
} incoming_data;
```

In this example, `incoming_data` is data imported from a file, where `dataTypeID` tells you what kind of data it is. (There are many file formats which optimize space in this fashion.)

Comment: I would downvote that, but I don't feel like you have anything wrong with your answer. Whereas that's a correct definition, it's really misleading to new programmers in terms of good coding practice. CPlusPlus.com is just not a good site at all.

Comment: I'll change the link, just suggest a better one. The real point of my answer is the second part (why unions are likely to be found).

Comment: I know cplusplus.com has some flaws. That doesn't mean the whole site is rubbish. There are so many incorrect/inaccruate answers on SO with upvotes as well. It doesnt't mean the whole of SO is bad.

Comment: @KingsIndian It's not flaws. It's just horrible coding practices. And this isn't just me talking... At least at SO, it can correct itself, but this isn't a site comparison contest. If that quote doesn't irk you, then you've been lucky enough to have to not have these kinds of issues.

Comment: @egrunin I don't think you need a link. You could remove the whole top half.

Comment: @LeeLouviere : Suggestion taken.